# Ruby get permutations of all lengths from a string in order

Tags: ruby, recursion

Here's my code-

```
$arr = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789_-"
def scan(f)
    begin
        if f.size == 6
              exit
        end
        $arr.each_char do |y|
            t =  f + y
            puts t
            scan(t)
        end
    end
end
```

I wish to print all permutations and lengths upto 6, I've tried this recursive approach. The output I get is -

```
A 
AA
AAA 
AAAA
AAAAA
```

However I seek something like this-

```
A
AA
AB
AC
.
.
AZ
AAA
AAB
.
.
AAZ
.
.
upto 6 chars
```

On commenting the recursive call I see that it prints

```
AA
AB
AC
.
.
```

Which is fine without recursion but not with recursion. Any kinds of suggestions are appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: [`Array#permutations`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-permutation) with a bit of extra logic might be helpful. Mobile right now, sorry can't offer more insight ATM.

Comment: That works but I need the values one by one , as I have to pass them to another function. Can't afford to use this in the beginning and save it in a list as it takes quite a while upto 5 characters.

Comment: It takes a block...  "When invoked with a block, yield all permutations of length n of the elements of the array, then return the array itself."

Comment: Should output contain strings like "ABA", "BAA", "BAB", "ZAA"?

Comment: Why does 'AAA' follow 'AZ'? Shouldn't it be 'AZ', 'Aa', 'Ab' ... 'A9', 'A_', 'A-', and then 'AAA'?

Comment: Yes it should @JagdeepSingh I was just illustrating my example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array#repeated_permutation can do the heavy lifting for you here:

```
$arr = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789_-"
def scan
  characters = $arr.chars

  (1..6).each do |length|
    characters.repeated_permutation(length) do |sequence|
      t = sequence.join
      puts t
    end
  end
end
```

Or as a more reusable enumerator:

```
CHARACTERS = [*"A".."Z", *"a".."z", *"0".."9", "_", "-"]
def each_permuted_string(max_length = 6, &block)
  sequences = (1..max_length).map { |n| CHARACTERS.repeated_permutation(n) }

  if block_given?
    sequences.each { |seq| seq.lazy.map(&:join).each(&block) }
  else
    enum_for(__method__, max_length) { sequences.map(&:size).inject(:+) }
  end
end

each_permuted_string do |t|
  puts t
end
```

It's going to take a *very* long time, though -- there are `each_permuted_string.size => 69810262080` values. This sounds like it could be an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/), and you might get a better solution by asking a question about the higher-level problem you're solving.

Comment: Yup exactly what I needed, one by one.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're expecting `A`, `AA`, `AAA`, etc... to be included in the resulted list, then you might find the [repeated_permutations](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-repeated_permutation) method to be useful, because you need permutations with repetitions.

Unfortunately, the number of permutations is extremely large (`$arr` contains 64 symbols) and permutations with up to 6 chars must be calculated. The number of permutations is:

```
64^7 = 4_398_046_511_104
```

But still, here's an example of calculating permutations of up to `6` chars:

```
(1..6).to_a.flat_map { |i| $arr.chars.repeated_permutation(i).map(&:join) }
```

Which is even for `4` is quite slow, but it's up to you.

Comment: Good for illustrating the sheer size of the problem. Even with the best efficiency, that is a quite a few samples, calculations, and new objects that will need created to solve this problem.