# Ruby continue recursion

Tags: ruby, recursion

```
$chars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
def run(s)
  begin
    if s.size == 6
      exit
    end
    $chars.each_char do |y|
      s = s + y
      puts s
      puts run(s)
    end
  end
end

run('A')
```

The above code outputs in this form -

```
AA
AAA
AAAA
AAAAA
AAAAAA
```

However I want it to continue to the next character, like -

```
AA
AB
AC
AD
.
.
AZ
AAA
AAB
AAC
AAD
.
.
AAZ
.
.
.
.
AZZ

.
.
.
AZZZZ
```

I was able to make it work with 4 loops however the I can't using recursion.
Any kind of help and suggestions is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: The same logic from [your question yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51692230/ruby-get-permutations-of-all-lengths-from-a-string-in-order) applies.

Comment: What's the real task here, the algorithmic part of the problem or the Ruby/coding style part? because you can use Ruby techniques that make your life much easier, but will black out part of the algorithmic practice here. Not to mention that your code has many issues Ruby-wise.

Comment: I agree with @TamerShlash. Is this an exercise for learning and understanding algorithms, or simply the need to accomplish a task?

Comment: My final goal is to code a brute Force approach. Like I need all 5 letter words starting with A of all lengths upto 5 i.e 2,3,4 letter words too. I have to implement this method in a bigger program.

Comment: @ForeverZer0 the yesterday's solution is fine but it generates words which don't need. For example if I need words starting with just A and T, the code even generates other words which increases the total time.

Comment: It would only require some very minor alterations to accomplish your goals.

Comment: So, it's significant that you pass in 'A' as a parameter, meaning you only want the permutations that start with the letter 'A'...so you would never have 'BA' -> 'ZZZZZZ', is that correct? Using the `repeated_permutation` suggested in yesterday's question, could you not just do the `repeated_permutation(desired_size - 1)` and prepend 'A' to all of those?

Comment: I was trying the exact the same thing. I think it'll do.Thanks .

Comment: You are aware `String#next` can handle this for you. For example `Z.next => "AA"`